# Board manager on arduino IDE not working

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, intel-galileo

I'm trying to use arduino IDE for the board arduino galileo gen2 but I'm getting this error:

> package_index.json file signature verification failed.

And the board manager is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your board system date before installing node packages. In you board SSH shell type `date -s "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` replacing the values with the respective date time